# Component loads outdated element list

Tags: css, angular, dom, width

The goal is to check each tab-element for its size in a variable tabrow:

Tabs are handled on window-resize, when a tab is added/opened, when a tab is closed, when the sequence of tabs changes through drag'n'drop.

I can successfully access the tab size via nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().width

**Problem:**
While I can access the tabs, I always seem to get the "outdated" list of tabs, i.e. I have 1 tab open and open another, this triggers the recalculation of the tabs in the tabrow, but it only prints the width for the tab that was already open, even though I can see the second tab in my UI and it was successfully opened and the correct list of tabs can be emitted into the component from the tab.service.ts

I've attempted with change detection to check when the number of elements in 'tabs' changes but received the same outdated list of elements.

```
export class AppTabRowComponent implements AfterViewInit {

...

    @ViewChildren('tabs') tabs: QueryList<ElementRef>;

    constructor(public tabService: TabService, public urlCheckerService: UrlCheckerService, 
        private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
        this.tabService.tablistChanged$.subscribe(tabs => {
          console.log('tabsList ', tabs);
        }); //Correct number of tabs are emitted into the component via subscribe

        this.tabService.tabRowChanged$.subscribe(action => {
         this.calculateTabSize();
        });
      }


    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        //calculating tabrow contents of pinnedTabs from previous session
        this.calculateTabSize();
        //attempt to subscribe to @ViewChildren('tabs') with changeDetection UNSUCCESSFUL
        this.tabs.changes.subscribe(() => {
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
          console.log('tabs after first add/remove/change');
        });
        this.calculateTabSize();
      }

    public calculateTabSize() {
        this.tabs.forEach(x => {
          const width = x.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().width;
          console.log('single tab width: ', width);
        });
      }
...
}
```

```
@Injectable()
export class TabService {
    tabs: AppTabData[] = [];
    private tabListChangedSignal: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

...

    tablistChanged$: Observable<AppTabData[]> = this.tabListChangedSignal.asObservable();

//triggers the recalculation of tabs in the component
    private addTab(newTab: AppTabData, openInBackground: boolean): void {
        this.tabs.push(newTab);
        this.emitTabList(this.tabs);
        this.emitTabAction(TAB_ACTIONS.TAB_ADDED);
        if (!openInBackground) {
          this.switchActiveTab(newTab);
        }
      }

    emitTabList(tabs: AppTabData[]): void {
        this.tabListChangedSignal.next(tabs);
      }

...
}
```

Can you tell me why I can see the additional tab being added in my UI, but it not showing up "on time" when I access the tabs via @ViewChildren and an approach how to get the current list of tabs?

Or is there another way to get the width other than through @ViewChildren?

Comment: After trying to find the "right way" to solve this, I found a shitty fix, by surrounding my calculateTabisze method with a timeout.

I will spend more time on this and maybe find a better solution, but sometimes things - especially frontend things can only be solved with a shitty fix.